# Adding use to the home button

Tags: android

When you press the home button, what does it do by default?

I want to keep what it does by default, but make sure it ends my music as well.

For example:

public void onBackPressed() {
    return;

I disabled my back button.

I want to make it so the home button does what it does, but i want to call my 
this.stopService(new Intent(this, Music.class));
in the method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to override "Home" key press just like you did for Back button press. In fact you're not supposed to over ride home key press because user presses Home key to quickly come to the launcher.
Even if you try to override onKeyDown(), you'll see that Home key press will not invoke this function.

But pressing Home key will surely call onStop() of your activity and hence you can stop your music service in onStop(). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> When you press the home button, what does it do by default?

It brings the home screen activity to the foreground.

> I want to keep what it does by default, but make sure it ends my music as well.

Stop the music in `onPause()` or `onStop()` of your foreground activity, as these will be called when it loses the foreground to the home screen activity.

Comment: @user1274830: It does not change my answer, other than to tell you to delete your `onBackPressed()` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking in coding sense -

The home button brings the default launcher to the foreground.

Call onPause() or onStop with super.onPause() or super.onStop() inside of the method.

If you are talking in literal terms with nothing to do with code then..

The home button launches the default launcher activity, this can be cleared if you installed the launcher on some devices by going settings > applications > manage find the application and then go clear defaults

When the music stops is decided by the developers code, you cant change how it works sorry.